# Checking values within tuple that contains only booleans

Tags: swift, tuples

I've constructed a tuple:

```
var groupUsersFlags = (false, false, false, false)
```

Throughout the screen these values get flipped over to true. So:

```
groupUsersFlags.0 = true
groupUsersFlags.1 = true
etc..
```

Is there any way to check if all the values are true at some point?

Comment: `groupUsersFlags.0 && groupUsersFlags.1 && groupUsersFlags.2 && groupUsersFlags.3`?

Comment: Yep, that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with the idea of using another data type in this case.
However, to answer the question, you can check if all the values are true like this:

```
groupUsersFlags.0 && groupUsersFlags.1 && groupUsersFlags.2 && groupUsersFlags.3
```

Or, using reflection (use as your own risk):

```
Mirror(reflecting: groupUsersFlags).children.reduce(true) { $0 && $1.value as! Bool }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let x = Mirror(reflecting: groupUsersFlags)
    var isAllTrue = true

 for value in x.children.enumerate() where value.element.value as? Bool != nil{
    if value.element.value as! Bool == false {
        isAllTrue = false
        break
    }
}
```

Try out this solution.